# What specifically allows alpha-complementation in beta-galactosidase?

Tags: proteins, biotechnology

I'm familiar with the use of alpha-complementation of beta-galactosidase with the pUC alpha-peptide and the M15 lacZ gene product, and would like to hypothetically apply alpha-complementation in other settings with different enzymes. I do have a few questions, but hopefully they are similar enough to all be answered here.

- What specifically allows for the non-covalent association between both truncated protein products to form a functional beta-galactosidase? How is beta-galactosidase unique in that separating it into two portions still yields a functional enzyme (in other words, why wouldn't other enzymes remain functional if I split them)?
- What other proteins, if any, have been engineered to perform similar alpha-complementation? What steps were taken to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe this review is a good start: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22070901

Comment: Two other (free) papers on beta-gal complementation and other split reporter systems: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2835542/ http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC137764/